# ajax beginForm to ignore specified buttons

Tags: c#, jquery, html, ajax

is there a way to get AjaxBeginForms to ignore some specified buttons?

for example my code is:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreatePost", "Accounts", new AjaxOptions
{
   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
   HttpMethod = "POST",
   LoadingElementId = "loading",
   OnBegin = "TransferContentEditableToHiddenTextArea()",
   OnSuccess = "$('#CreateMessage').css('display','block');",
   UpdateTargetId = "CreateMessage"
}))
{
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   @Html.Label("Post Title", new { @style = "padding-right:3px;" })
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BlogTitle, new { @required = "require", @style = "width:100%;", @class = "form-control" })

   @Html.Label("Post Blog", new { @style = "padding-right:3px;" })
   <ul id="postModifierButtonsGroup">
      <li><span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-bold"></i></span></li>
      <li><span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-italic"></i></span></li>
      <li><span class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" ><i class="fa fa-underline"></i></span></li>
   </ul>
   <p class="form-control" id="contentEditableTextBox" contenteditable="true"></p>
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.BlogPost, new { id = "hiddenTextbox", @required = "require", @style = "display:none;resize: none; width:100%; height: 130px; font: 16px tahoma;", @class = "form-control" })

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit"/>
}
```

so i have 2 fields a post and a title which are going into the ajax call with the c# backend. the problem is i just added bold, italics, and underline buttons and they are conflicting with the ajax form. if i want to add bold to me text the form has an attempted submission. 
Is there a way to specify on a button that it is not to be part of my ajax call?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want a button to submit a form you can add this attribute:

```
type="button"
```

If any button is marked as type="submit" inside of a form, it will submit that form.